# How to select the row which matches a complex WHERE clause and has the minimum value in a given column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, where-clause

I need to select a row from a table which must satisfy the following conditions:

- It needs to match a quite complex WHERE clause
- It needs to have the minimum value in column X

Thus far, the only working solution I have is this:

```
SELECT <columns>
FROM <table>
WHERE <complex WHERE clause>
AND <columnX> = (SELECT MIN(<columnX>) FROM <table> WHERE <same WHERE clause as before>)
```

This strikes me as quite ugly and cumberstome, having to repeat the same (complex) WHERE clause two times.

Do you know any better way to achieve this?

Comment: `Complex where clause` isnt really helpful unless I can see how complex it is. And if you are using this complex where against both tables then you will need to use it twice. Yes something that can put this complex where clause away is a `View`, with that WHERE clause in the definition and use them views in your queries instead using table names and having to write where clauses again n again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out the easiest solution was ordering...

```
SELECT TOP 1 <columns>
FROM <table>
WHERE <complex WHERE clause>
ORDER BY <ColumnX> ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, I would use a CTE (Common Table Expression) to write the complex query and have the  where clause reference to it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a view or temporary table, the performance difference varying heavily on the actual problem (you could try both):

```
CREATE VIEW v AS
SELECT <columns>
FROM <table>
WHERE <complex WHERE clause>;

SELECT * FROM v
WHERE <columnX> = SELECT min(<columnX> FROM v);
```

Or even better, taking advantage of the window functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        <columns>,
        MIN(<columnX>) OVER () AS minX
    FROM <table>
    WHERE <complex WHERE clause>
) t
WHERE <columnX> = minX;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0a52b/6/0

This latter should certainly read the table only once.

Comment: Both of them work. But ordering and selecting the top row is a lot simpler.

Comment: @Massimo there is one semantic difference: if you have duplicate minimum values, your original query (in the question) and mines return all of them, while TOP 1 returns an arbitrary one. -- which one is preferred depends on the application.